# Logging transformation metadata information(counts) using Apache Spark and mysql

Tags: apache-spark

Currently, I have few spark jobs which are performing multiple transformations and generating an output file.

Assume I have below transformations(**just an assumption**):

```
RDD1 = sc.textFile(file1)
RDD2 = sc.textFile(file2)
RDD3 =RDD1.filter(logic)
RDD4 = RDD3.UNION(RDD2)
....
....
```

Currently, I am logging record count of each step into a MySQL table like below:

```
RDD1 INPUT 1000
RDD1 OUTPUT 1000

RDD3 INPUT 1000
RDD3 OUTPUT 700
```

As there are only a few jobs currently, performance is not a bottleneck.
Going forward, I am expecting many jobs are running in parallel and each one of them performing the same kind of logging.

Since multiple jobs try to log information into a single table, there are more chances to get performance issue, and this logging can become a bottleneck.

Is there a best way in spark to read each transformations input and output records easily rather than writing code(action) to log to retrieve those counts?

Also, looking for the best way to log this information into the database other than connecting to the database and inserting records for each transformation during runtime? Any suggestions if I can use other than mysql for my logging (Like Hive/Impala)?

Comment: If you don't need the count in real time, maybe you can write the count as a file to hdfs and then batch load these count files to your db.

Comment: @Falan, Yes, thought of same approach as it is a near real time process.But, even in that case also, loading into table will become a bottle neck as there will be multiple processes running and creating these files(spark jobs) as well as another jobs that file into db. These job number might increase day by day.  Used KAFKA as well to load into table, and that approach is resulting the same. So, thinking if mysql is a good option or can we go for anyother databases like hive or impala for logging this metadata information.

Comment: then sounds like hive or impala will be a good use case here.